# Vue.js v-for on list items, looking up array object by id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

So I have an array of objects from json that looks like this:

[image: array of obj]

I'm generating a `<ul>` and for each `<li>` I get an ID from an API:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="genre in movie.genre_ids">
    {{ genre }} // 19
  </li>
</ul>
```

I do not want to display the number, I would like the name of the genre, which is a sibling of the object that contains that ID.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your `genres` array into an object whose keys are the IDs:

```js
computed: {
  genresFormatted() {
    const genres = {};
    this.genres.forEach(genre => {
      genres[genre.id] = genre.name;
    });
    return genres;
  }
}
```

Now it's much easier to get the `name` property when looping:

```html
<li v-for="id in movie.genre_ids" :key="id">
  {{ genresFormatted[id] }}
</li>
```